# What network port to use for mobile app

Tags: mobile, network-programming

I currently have a mobile app that uses a socket connection to communicate with a server. However, it seems that some users are complaining that the port is blocked by their ISP, or wireless network.

Is there a range of ports that are are well-known enough to not be blocked but also not used by mobile devices that I could use? Or is there a better way to address this issue?

Asking the ISP/wireless network admin to unblock a port is currently not the most feasible thing for me to do.

EDIT: I'm looking at Canadian, US, and European mobile operators in particular.

Comment: BTW including country/network might also help other users to give you better advice based on experience with those networks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best and only port to use would be 
80 standard http traffic.

You could also try...
443 SSL http traffic
8080 backup HTTP traffic port normally used for proxy servers or the links.

But honestly if you are even remotely worried about networks blocking your traffic standard HTTP and port 80 are the only ways to go. Most networks will allow port 80 if they allow any thing.

BTW some times the only way is to ask the ISPs/Networks to open up that port to your server this isn't ideal but if they block port 80 you are going to have to ask them.